# Why does passing the value from a constructor var to the class variable fail in my code? c++

Tags: c++, setter, getter

in the constructor of my class I want to read out the filepath of the programm and pass it to a class variable, but it says "undeclared identifier"

Here are my .H and .cpp files:

```
    #ifndef GEHEIMESTAGEBUCH_H
    #define GEHEIMESTAGEBUCH_H

    #include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
    #include "ui_geheimestagebuch.h"
    #include "login.h"
    #include "hauptfenster.h"


    class GeheimesTagebuch : public QMainWindow
    {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    GeheimesTagebuch(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GeheimesTagebuch();
     wstring privatepath;
     wstring getpath()
    {
         return privatepath;
     }


    private:


    Ui::GeheimesTagebuchClass ui;

    accountanlegen * anlegen;
    SimpleCrypt * simple1;
    Hauptfenster * Haupt;

    public slots:

        void update();
        void accountanl();
    };

    #endif // GEHEIMESTAGEBUCH_H
```

and my .cpp file:

```
#include "geheimestagebuch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

GeheimesTagebuch::GeheimesTagebuch(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui.pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accountanl()));
     anlegen=new accountanlegen();
    Haupt=new Hauptfenster();
    simple1=new SimpleCrypt(123321123321);
     anlegen->setVisible(false);
     Haupt->setVisible(false);



    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    wstring path1(buffer);
    wstring p1=L"\\/";
    wstring::size_type pos = wstring(path1).find_last_of( p1 );
    path1=path1.substr(0,pos);
    privatepath=path1;

}

GeheimesTagebuch::~GeheimesTagebuch()
{

}

void GeheimesTagebuch::update()
{

//unnecessery code. I can show if you want.
}

void GeheimesTagebuch::accountanl()
{


    if(anlegen->isVisible()==false)
        anlegen->show();
}
```

Why does the last line does not work?

```
GeheimesTagebuch::GeheimesTagebuch(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    privatepath=path1;
}
```

This is my Main question. My Endgoal is to use a getter Method to pass the variable privatepath to another class.

Here is as requested my unedited error output.

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: GeheimesTagebuch, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  geheimestagebuch.cpp
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(17): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'privatepath'
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(17): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(18): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'getpath'
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(18): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(19): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(21): warning C4183: 'getpath': Rückgabetyp fehlt; Memberfunktion, die 'int' zurückgibt wird angenommen
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(20): error C2065: 'privatepath': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
1>geheimestagebuch.cpp(28): error C2065: 'privatepath': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
1>  moc_geheimestagebuch.cpp
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\generatedfiles\debug\../../geheimestagebuch.h(17): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'privatepath'
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\generatedfiles\debug\../../geheimestagebuch.h(17): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\generatedfiles\debug\../../geheimestagebuch.h(18): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'getpath'
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\generatedfiles\debug\../../geheimestagebuch.h(18): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\generatedfiles\debug\../../geheimestagebuch.h(19): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\generatedfiles\debug\../../geheimestagebuch.h(21): warning C4183: 'getpath': Rückgabetyp fehlt; Memberfunktion, die 'int' zurückgibt wird angenommen
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\generatedfiles\debug\../../geheimestagebuch.h(20): error C2065: 'privatepath': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(17): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'privatepath'
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(17): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(18): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ';' vor Bezeichner 'getpath'
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(18): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(19): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(21): warning C4183: 'getpath': Rückgabetyp fehlt; Memberfunktion, die 'int' zurückgibt wird angenommen
1>c:\users\steffen\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch\geheimestagebuch.h(20): error C2065: 'privatepath': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner
1>  Code wird generiert...
========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, 1 fehlerhaft, 0 aktuell, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

Good day

Steven

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean by that? Do you get compilation errors? What errors do you get in that case? Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error output.

Comment: My German's a bit rusty, but I guess it doesn't recognise `wstring`, since it's not declared in the class or the global namespace. You probably want `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `wstring` in the `geheimestagebuch.h` file should be a `std::wstring`.
You might want to include `string`, too. At least this is what those errors say, the compiler is not able to find the type `wstring`.

Comment: Thank you NaCI now it works. It was my fail. I did not consider this, because visual studio marked it as known type with colour.